High CPU Usage and lag in LinuxMint: performance Issues and Solutions
I open some programs (maybe limited to games, or maybe the problem lies deeper) on my Linux Mint, and when I check their status using the top command in the terminal, I see that they completely use 3 CPU cores! (This was for a very simple game (BombSquad)). The program itself only takes up about 100 MB of space, and I'm sure there's no problem with the program. I have run it on Linux before, and it used to run very smoothly, but now it is very laggy and unusable.
I should add that the programs work perfectly fine on Windows without any issues (even heavy programs), and this is still the case. If I reinstall Windows, the programs run well.
I should also mention that any video I watch on my Linux Mint (even if I have downloaded it) is very slow and laggy, and I have to watch it in fragments, which is terrible.
I used the command taskset -c 1 ./bombsquad to run the program using only one core. This slightly reduced the speed (I still couldn't control the mouse movement in the program well; it was very slow and I could still clearly see the lag in the program).
I have updated my Linux in every aspect and used the sudo apt autoremove command to improve my system.
I deleted Windows hoping it would solve my problem; but it didn't (I really had to because running some programs or games is very important to me as I need to work on them and develop them as quickly as possible).
This situation is really catastrophic for me; I would appreciate any help you can offer.

Brand/model? Which graphics card? If Nvidia do you have the correct drivers installed and running? Everything you report points to graphics issues. Furthermore autoremove has absolutely NOTHING to do with performance. It merely deletes orphan packages and orphan packages occupy (very little) space, nothing else. Please [edit] the question to provide the info requested at the beginning of this comment.
